# PROBLEMA Form onchange me borra campos ya escritos

Tags: php, html, formularios, select, entrada

buenas tardes.
Tengo un problema y quisiera saber si alguien podría echarme un cable.

Tengo un formulario: en ciertos campos, utilizo en los select la propiedad onchange="this.form.submit()", para que me envíe el valor mediante $_POST, guardarlo en una variable, y utilizarlo en otro campo...

El problema, viene, que, al rellenar campos de texto, y después rellenar alguno de estos select, todos los campos

```html
<form id="pedidost" method="POST">

  <label for="familiasod">Familia de lentes:</label>

   <select name="familiasod" onchange="this.form.submit()">
     <option value="1od" disabled>-- Seleccione tipo de lentes --</option>
     <option value="stockod" selected>Monofocal Stock</option>
     <option value="labod">Monofocal Fabricacion</option>
     <option value="progresivosod">Progresivos</option>
     <option value="bifocalesod">Bifocales</option>
   </select>

  <input name="fecha" id="fecha" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>" size="7">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Referencia">

  <select name="remoto" >
    <option value="" selected disabled>- Sin Cortar / Biselado -</option>
    <option value="uncut">Sin Cortar Lente</option>
    <option value="edged">Biselado Remoto</option>
  </select>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="column">
   <h4>Lente Ojo Derecho</h4>

     <select name="stock_od" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccione diseño </option>
           <?php
                  /* creamos la consulta */
                  $result=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM disenyos where id_familia = 1;");

                  /* utilizamos un ciclo repetitivo para obtener los datos de la tabla */            

                  while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                      /* preguntamos si es el seleccionado por el usuario */
                      if (isset($_POST['stock_od'])){

                      if($valores['id_disenyo']==$_POST['stock_od']){
                      ?>

                      <!-- Llenamos el select con lo seleccionado por el usuario -->
                      <!-- Agrego el id del diseño como valor del campo -->
                      <option value="<?php echo $valores['id_disenyo'] ?>"selected> <?php echo $valores['nombre']; ?> </option>

                     <?php 
                       }

                      else {
                           ?>
                     <!-- Llenamos el select con los datos de la tabla -->
                     <!-- Agrego el id del diseño como valor del campo -->
                     <option value="<?php echo $valores['id_disenyo'] ?>"> <?php echo $valores['nombre']; ?> </option>   
                     <?php                    
                          } /* cierre del else $valores*/ 
                       } /* cierre del if del isset */

                      else {
                     ?>
                      <!-- Llenamos el select con los datos de la tabla -->
                      <!-- Agrego el id del diseño como valor del campo -->
                      <option value="<?php echo $valores['id_disenyo'] ?>"> <?php echo $valores['nombre']; ?> </option>   
                      <?php                    
                                  } /* cierre del else del isset*/
                      } /* cierre del while */
                      ?>
          </select>
```

No añado más código porque no lo veo necesario, se supone que al hacer click en cualquier valor del select con "name="stock_od", si había algo escrito en "Referencia" lo elimina.

Necesitaría que porfavor alguien me ayudara.

Saludos.

Comment: No me queda muy claro, pero creo que se te borra porque al hacer submit() envía los datos y refresca el formulario. Deberías de buscar otra forma de hacer eso, te recomiendo añadir alguna función de javascript.

Comment: Si, pero con ciertos campos no lo hace, únicamente con los <input type="text"> como en este caso Referencia. Estoy intentando buscar una alternativa que no sea javascript, ya que me tocaría rehacer muchas muchas líneas de código :/